# Maximize $\det (A)$ subject to $\|A\|_{\text{F}} \le 1$

Tags: matrices, optimization

> $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix such that the sum of squares of its elements is less than or equal to 1.
>
> What is $\max \det (A)$?
>
> (a) $n = 2$
>
> (b) $n = 3$

**My partial solution**

For $n = 2$, I think the answer is 0.5. Define the constrained maximisation problem as $$\max(a_{11}a_{22}-a_{21}a_{12})$$ such that $$a_{11}^2+a_{12}^2+a_{21}^2+a_{22}^2 \le 1$$
If $a_{21}=a_{12}=0$, the maximum $0.5$ is achieved at $a_{11}=a_{22}=1/\sqrt{2}$.

If $a_{21} \ne 0, a_{12}\ne0$, the maximum $0.5$ is achieved at $a_{11}=a_{22}=a_{21}=0.5$ and $a_{12}=-0.5$

But how to I prove that formally? And how to I tackle the more difficult case of $n=3$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ be the column vectors of $A$.
By [Hadamard's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard's_inequality), we have
$$\det(A) = \prod_{i=1}^n \|v_i\|$$
We are told the sum of squares of $A$'s  elements $\le 1$. In terms of $v_i$, this
means
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \|v_i\|^2 = 1$$
By GM $\le$ AM, we have

$$\left(\prod_{i=1}^n \|v_i\|^2\right)^{1/n} \le \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n \|v_i\|^2 = \frac1n
\quad\implies\quad\det(A) \le \frac{1}{n^{n/2}}$$
Notice when $A = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} I_n$, the equality on RHS is achieved. 
This means above inequality is an optimal one.

**Update**

People seem to be interested in an explicit proof for the $n = 3$ case.
For completeness, here is a proof of Hadamard's inequality at $n = 3$.
Notice

1. For $3 \times 3$ matrix $A$ with columns $v_1,v_2,v_3$; we have  $\det A = v_1 \cdot (v_2 \times v_3)$.
2. For any $u, v \in \mathbb{R}^3$, we have the vector identity $|u|^2 |v|^2 = (u\cdot v)^2 + |u \times v|^2$.

We find
$$\begin{align}|\det A|^2 
&= |v_1 \cdot (v_2 \times v_3)|^2 = |v_1|^2|v_2 \times v_3|^2 -
|v_1 \times (v_2 \times v_3)|^2\\
&= |v_1|^2|v_2|^2|v_3|^2 - ( |v_1|^2 (v_2 \cdot v_3)^2 +
|v_1 \times (v_2 \times v_3)|^2)\\ &\le |v_1|^2|v_2|^2|v_3|^2
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Can you please explain the notation - dot product and $\times$ product?

Comment: @VictorRogulenko At 3-dim, the $3\times 1$ column vectors has $1-1$ correspondence with ordinary vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$. The $\cdot$ and $\times$ are the standard dot and cross products in [vector calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe one should look at $\det (A)$ as a volume of cube spanned by its rows. Then $\det (A)$ is maximal when the rows are perpendicular, and in this case $\det (A)$ is the product of the lengths of the rows. So, the problem reduces to the classical inequality between arithmetical and geometrical means.

Comment: this looks like a very nice idea, but it would be nice if you could give more details

Comment: if A has rows r_1,r_2, ... ,r_n then  |detA| ^2 <= ||r_1||^2 ||r_2||^2 ... <= (||r_1||^2 + ||r_2||^2 + .../N)^N

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly, maximizing the **logarithm** of the determinant is a **convex** optimization problem.

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & \log \det( \mathrm A)\\ \text{subject to} & \| \mathrm A \|_{\text{F}}\leq 1\end{array}$$

Using [CVXPY](http://www.cvxpy.org) to solve the convex program numerically for $n \in \{2,3,\dots,9\}$:

```
from cvxpy import *
import numpy as np

for n in range(2,10):

    print "\n\nn = ", n, "\n"

    A  = Variable(n,n)

    # create convex optimization problem
    prob = Problem( Maximize(log_det(A)),
                    [norm(A,'fro') <= 1] )

    # solve optimization problem
    prob.solve()

    # print rounding of optimal matrix A 
    print np.round(A.value, 3)
```

which produces the following output:

```
n =  2 

[[ 0.706 -0.   ]
 [-0.     0.706]]


n =  3 

[[ 0.576 -0.     0.   ]
 [-0.     0.576 -0.   ]
 [ 0.    -0.     0.576]]


n =  4 

[[ 0.499 -0.    -0.    -0.   ]
 [-0.     0.499 -0.     0.   ]
 [ 0.    -0.     0.499  0.   ]
 [-0.     0.    -0.     0.499]]


n =  5 

[[ 0.447  0.     0.    -0.    -0.   ]
 [-0.     0.447 -0.     0.     0.   ]
 [ 0.     0.     0.447  0.     0.   ]
 [-0.     0.    -0.     0.447 -0.   ]
 [ 0.     0.     0.    -0.     0.447]]


n =  6 

[[ 0.407 -0.    -0.     0.     0.    -0.   ]
 [-0.     0.407  0.    -0.    -0.     0.   ]
 [-0.     0.     0.407  0.     0.     0.   ]
 [ 0.    -0.    -0.     0.407 -0.    -0.   ]
 [ 0.    -0.     0.    -0.     0.407 -0.   ]
 [ 0.     0.     0.    -0.    -0.     0.407]]


n =  7 

[[ 0.377 -0.     0.     0.     0.    -0.    -0.   ]
 [ 0.     0.377  0.     0.    -0.    -0.    -0.   ]
 [-0.    -0.     0.377  0.     0.    -0.     0.   ]
 [ 0.     0.    -0.     0.377 -0.    -0.    -0.   ]
 [ 0.    -0.    -0.     0.     0.377 -0.     0.   ]
 [-0.     0.    -0.    -0.    -0.     0.377  0.   ]
 [-0.     0.     0.    -0.     0.     0.     0.377]]


n =  8 

[[ 0.353 -0.    -0.     0.     0.     0.    -0.    -0.   ]
 [ 0.     0.353  0.     0.     0.    -0.     0.    -0.   ]
 [ 0.     0.     0.353 -0.     0.    -0.    -0.    -0.   ]
 [-0.    -0.    -0.     0.353 -0.     0.     0.     0.   ]
 [-0.    -0.     0.    -0.     0.353 -0.     0.     0.   ]
 [ 0.    -0.    -0.    -0.    -0.     0.353 -0.    -0.   ]
 [ 0.     0.    -0.    -0.     0.    -0.     0.353  0.   ]
 [-0.    -0.    -0.     0.     0.    -0.    -0.     0.353]]


n =  9 

[[ 0.333  0.    -0.     0.     0.    -0.    -0.    -0.     0.   ]
 [ 0.     0.333 -0.     0.    -0.    -0.    -0.     0.    -0.   ]
 [-0.    -0.     0.333 -0.    -0.     0.     0.    -0.     0.   ]
 [ 0.    -0.    -0.     0.333 -0.    -0.    -0.    -0.     0.   ]
 [ 0.    -0.    -0.    -0.     0.333 -0.    -0.     0.    -0.   ]
 [ 0.    -0.     0.    -0.     0.     0.333  0.     0.    -0.   ]
 [-0.    -0.     0.    -0.    -0.    -0.     0.333 -0.     0.   ]
 [-0.     0.    -0.    -0.     0.    -0.    -0.     0.333 -0.   ]
 [-0.    -0.     0.    -0.    -0.     0.     0.    -0.     0.333]]
```

which suggests that the optimal solution is indeed

$$\mathrm A = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \mathrm I_n$$

as [stated](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2792870/339790) by achille.

Comment: actually you have the implicit additional constraint that $\det(A)>0$ don't you?

Comment: @Surb Would that be convex? $\rm A \succeq O$ would.

Comment: I don't know if it would be, probably not. But then, how can you be sure that the unconstrained maximum is attained at a psd matrix?

Comment: @Surb I have no experience with $\max \log \det$ — other than this answer. This was purely experimental. I was surprised it worked and forgot about $\rm A \succeq O$. Pure luck, I assume.

Answer (score 1):

For $n=2$, you can use the inequality $a_{11} a_{22} \le 0.5(a_{11}^2+a_{22}^2)$ and the same for $a_{21}$, $a_{12}$ to see that

$$a_{11}a_{22}-a_{21}a_{12} \le \frac{a_{11}^2+a_{22}^2+a_{12}^2+a_{21}^2}{2} = \frac 12$$.

For the case $n=3$ look here:
Update: no, it was not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. $n=2$ is neat and clear. I'm not yet sure about $n=3$. Seems like @achille hui is right and the answer is $\frac{1}{3\sqrt{3}}$. I'm trying to find a matrix A for which $\det(A)=1/3$

Comment: Ok, I think https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/363582/maximum-and-minimum-of-determinant refers to a slightly different problem ("*each* vectors' norm is 1" vs sum of squares of *all* elements $\le 1$)